# perl tcl Tclkit link to specific installation

Tags: perl, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

How do I link the tcl.pm module to a Tclkit, like the one available [here](https://www.zolli.fr/tclkit-darwin.php), on macOS?

As an alternative, I would also be happy to link Tcl.pm to a normal Tcl/Tk installation. As stated in Tcl.pod, this should be done while compiling the module. They write:

```
perl Makefile.PL --library=-l/path/to/tcl(stub).a         \
   --include=-I/path/to/tcl/include                       \
   --define="-DLIB_RUNTIME_DIR=... -DTCL_LIB_FILE=..."
```

So, to give it a try, I took the preinstalled Tcl/Tk frameworks available on my macOS, moved it to another directory and then tried to Makefile.pl with the following parameters:

```
perl Makefile.PL \
   --library="-L/xxx/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5 -ltclstub8.5" \
   --include=-I/xxx/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers        \
   --define="-DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCLSH_PATH=\\\"/usr/bin\\\" -DLIB_RUNTIME_DIR=\\\"/xxx/Tcl.framework\\\" -DTCL_LIB_FILE=\\\"Tcl\\\""
```

Then I proceed with the normal make, make test and make install. I do not get any error that can point to a solution. I compared the make file created by the Makefile.pl without parameters and mine, and found no differences beside: the path (obviously), and that my makefile missed the line:

```
#     dynamic_lib => { OTHERLDFLAGS=>q[-framework Carbon] }
```

No matter what I try, my scripts get launched with the standard Tcl/Tk... I have no idea what I can try next

Comment: I've reformatted your code snippets to not have line breaks in crazy locations.

Comment: A solution to what?  What are the errors?  What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tcl module does not require you to set different details (`--library`, `--include`, `--define`) on your own, but you may refer to an installed `tclsh` or a `tclConfig.sh` to have them loaded automatically.

See `--tclconfig` and `--tclsh` when running:

```
% perl Makefile.PL --help
```

This just worked for me, both using a Tcl installation obtained via MacPorts (`sudo port install tcl`; 8.6.8) and an installation starting from a Tcl fossil checkout (`core-8-6-branch`).

```
% tar -xzf Tcl-1.27.tar.gz
% cd Tcl-1.27/
% perl Makefile.PL --tclconfig /opt/local/lib/tclConfig.sh
% make
% make test
```

This gives me:

```
$ make test
"/opt/local/bin/perl5.26" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Tcl.bs blib/arch/auto/Tcl/Tcl.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/opt/local/bin/perl5.26" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/call.t ............. ok     
t/constants.t ........ ok   
t/createcmd.t ........ ok   
t/disposal-subs-a.t .. skipped: because: not installed use Devel::Refcount qw( refcount )
t/disposal-subs-b.t .. ok   
t/disposal-subs-c.t .. ok   
t/disposal-subs-d.t .. ok   
t/disposal-subs-e.t .. ok   
t/disposal-subs-f.t .. ok   
t/disposal-subs.t .... 1/2 [[::perl::CODE(0x7fe3e3802a68) ::perl::Eval; ]]
t/disposal-subs.t .... ok   
t/eval.t ............. ok   
t/export_to_tcl.t .... ok   
t/info.t ............. ok   
t/memleak-a.t ........ skipped: because: not installed use Devel::Refcount qw( refcount )
t/result.t ........... ok   
t/set-callback.t ..... ok   
t/subclass.t ......... ok   
t/trace.t ............ ok   
t/unicode.t .......... ok   
t/var.t .............. ok   
All tests successful.

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/info.t           (Wstat: 0 Tests: 6 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   2
Files=20, Tests=101, 15 wallclock secs ( 0.08 usr  0.03 sys +  0.99 cusr  0.32 csys =  1.42 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Comment: I might be wrong, never tried, but I would not expect a tclkit to serve the purpose. This is because a tclkit does not expose the dependencies to Tcl.pm (which are stored in a virtual file system within the standalone executable). You'd rather use a [KitDLL](https://kitcreator.rkeene.org/fossil/wiki?name=KitDLL).

Comment: Thank you. This way I was able to run Makefile.PL without errors with a local installation of Tcl. I was not able however to use a KitDLL as the Makefile complains about tclConfig.sh. I am starting to think that I have a lot to learn about Tcl/Tk as it seems more complicated as initially thought.

Comment: I would not blame Tcl/ Tk for any of this :) There are different ways of deploying and installing it, indeed, but this is not make it any more complex than comparable environments. As for KitDLL: You will have to use the [SDK archive](https://kitcreator.rkeene.org/fossil/wiki?name=KitDLL+SDK) that comes along with a KitDLL, which contains the tclConfig.sh for your purposes.